# (xpath in python) I'd like to select a node which doesn't have "body" as its ancestor

Tags: python, xml, lxml, elementtree

I'd like to select a node which doesn't have  as its ancestor.

for example,

```
<root>
  <e>
    <head>
       <id>3</id>
       <word>abandon</word>
    </head>
    <body>
       <head>
          <word>accept</word>
       </head>
    </body>
  </e>
</root>
```

I want to select the first  element, not second one.

I tried:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.fromstring(fin).getroot()
word = root.find('.//word[not(ancestor::body)]')
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: http://effbot.org/zone/element-xpath.htm

Comment: As you can see from the link. xpath support in ElementTree is limited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [XPath 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) with [lxml](http://lxml.de/):

```
import lxml.etree as ET

fin = '''\
<root>
  <e>
    <head>
       <id>3</id>
       <word>abandon</word>
    </head>
    <body>
       <head>
          <word>accept</word>
       </head>
    </body>
  </e>
</root>'''


root = ET.fromstring(fin)
word = root.xpath('.//word[not(ancestor::body)]')
print(ET.tostring(word[0]))
# <word>abandon</word>
```